# Como utilizar PriEngine.Engine.Comercial.Clientes.DaProximoNumeroCBL()

Tags: c#

Na criação de Clientes via

```
Interop.GcpBE900.GcpBECliente PrCli = new Interop.GcpBE900.GcpBECliente();
.......
PriEngine.Engine.Comercial.Clientes.Actualiza(PrCli);
```

onde se poderá enquadrar o :

```
PriEngine.Engine.Comercial.Clientes.DaProximoNumeroCBL()
```

na criação da ficha do cliente ?

Não encontro no PrCLi.Set_????? o ligactb.

Obrigado
Pedro Figueiredo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boas, para fazeres a ligação da entidade à Contabilidade, usas:

```
PriEngine.Engine.Contabilidade.ConfiguracaoTabCBL
Interop.CblBE900.CblBECnfTabLigCBL
Interop.CblBE900.CblBECnfTabExercicioLigCBL
Interop.CblBE900.CblBECnfTabLinhaLigCBL
```

Terás de criar a conta no plano de contas para o exercício pretendido:

```
PriEngine.Engine.Contabilidade.PlanoContas
Interop.CblBE900.CblBEConta
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. 5*

Comment: De nada, já agora marca como válida a resposta ;)